# Django User model UpdateView "No URL to redirect to"

Tags: django

I want to be able to edit existing users info (like first name etc.) from users panel. I have a list of all users displayed and when I press "edit" button I get **"No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model."** error.

Here is some of my code:

```
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
    pk_url_kwarg = 'user_id'
    template_name = 'companies/user_update.html'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^users/$', views.user_index, name='user_index'),
# /company/user/<id>
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.user_detail,
    name='user_detail'),
# /company/users/<id>/update/
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.UserUpdate.as_view(),
    name='user_update'),
```

I tried fixing it by adding this code to models.py, but I get same error

```
class UserMethods(User):
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('companies:user_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

        class Meta:
            proxy = True
```

I also tried adding this method to UpdateView in views.py, but with this I get
**"'UserUpdate' object has no attribute 'user_id'"**

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('companies:user_detail', kwargs={
        'user_id': self.user_id})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you put the `get_absolute_url` method on a proxy, rather than the User model itself? If you wanted to do this, you would have to use UserMethods as the model in your view.

But the fix for the other approach is to get the user_id from `self.object`:

```
return reverse('companies:user_detail', kwargs={'user_id': self.object.id})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your model.

```
class UserMethods(User):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('companies:user_detail', args=(self.id,))
```

Whenever you want to provide this url in the template just type `{{ object.get_absolute_url }}`.